# Make navbar responsive without changing custom css and effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a site using `jekyll` and used [this](http://dongchuan.github.io/) theme. However, the problem with this is that the site navbar has links, which do not collapse when opening the website in mobile. All in all, the navbar is not responsive at all. I want to make it responsive, without changing the css. What should I do? My site already has `bootstrap` and `jQuery` included.

This is the header html code:

```
 <header class="site-header">
    <div class="container">
        <a id="site-header-brand" href="/" title="xyz">
            site title
        </a>
        <nav class="site-header-nav" role="navigation">
            <a href="/"
               class=" site-header-nav-item hvr-underline-from-center"
               target=""
               title="Home">
                Home
            </a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.site-header{
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 40px 0 30px 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0 !important;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 103;

    color: #000;
    background: #fff;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.site-header-nav{
    float:right;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}

.site-header-nav-item {
    color: #000;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left:1.25rem;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.site-header {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.site-header.site-header-nav-scrolled {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: white;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0.125em 0.125em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0.125em 0.125em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0.125em 0.125em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0.125em 0.125em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
    box-shadow: 0 0.125em 0.125em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}
```

The javascript for scroll function:

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 55)
        {
            $('.site-header').addClass('site-header-nav-scrolled');
        } else {
            $('.site-header').removeClass('site-header-nav-scrolled');
        }
 });
```

Comment: if changing you CSS is not an option, what about adding to it? create a separate menu -with its own classes -  for mobile devices and use @media rules to display the appropriate menu to the appropriate device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create navbar collapse button and wrap the links in the button when in mobile. There is great example at [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use bootstrap in your site I use bootstrap navigation classes along with your navigation class to make it responsive and to collapse the links. You can customise the looks of below code by using CSS. Here is the code.

```
<header class="site-header navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Your Site Name</a>
    </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> 
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
           <li><a href="/"
               class=" site-header-nav-item hvr-underline-from-center"
               target=""
               title="Home">
                Home
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="/"
               class=" site-header-nav-item hvr-underline-from-center"
               target=""
               title="About">
                About
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="/"
               class=" site-header-nav-item hvr-underline-from-center"
               target=""
               title="Contact">
                Contact
            </a></li>
            </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
</header>
```